# C# - Taking a generic argument, use reflection to modify the properties, and return the generic argument

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to take in a generic argument, manipulate the properties of it via Reflection, and then return the generic type with the modified properties.

```
public IEnumerable<T> GenerateTest()
{
     var type = typeof(T);

foreach (var field in type.GetProperties())
                {
               // Modify / Set properties on variable type

                }

// How do I return object T with the parameters that I modified in the iteration above?
}
```

Comment: where is the object instance ? am not sure properties can be set in the for loop mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to create a new `T` object, you need to add the `new()` constraint to the type parameter:

```
class MyClass<T> where T : new()
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GenerateTest()
    {
```

Then you can create a new `T` object and set its properties:

```
        var obj = new T();

        foreach (var field in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            field.SetValue(obj, ...);
        }
```

Because your method returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can't return your `T` object directly but need to wrap in a collection:

```
        var list = new List<T>();
        list.Add(obj);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I'm just modifying the "type" variable (typeof T), how does that modify the actual T properties?

Comment: You can't modify a type. You can only set the properties of an object (unless the properties are static).